`RollupError: [commonjs--resolver] Expression expected` when building the project in Vite
I have a project that includes a React Native project and a Vite (React Native Web) project in a monorepo using pnpm. When I build the Vite project, I am getting the error:
error during build:
RollupError: [commonjs--resolver] Expression expected in `node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/calendar/index.js` 
89:     }, [onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight]);
90:     const renderWeekNumber = (weekNumber) => {
91:         return (<View style={style.current.dayContainer} key={`week-container-${weekNumber}`}>
                    ^
92:         <BasicDay key={`week-${weekNumber}`} marking={weekNumberMarking.current}
93:         // state='disabled'


where the node_modules is at the root directory of the monorepo.
It seems that rollup cannot resolve the jsx syntax in js file and mannually changing the js file in node_modules into jsx file does do the trick but there are quite a lot of js files in the package so I want to seek a better solution.
Here is part of my vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import relay from 'vite-plugin-relay-lite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import webfontDownload from 'vite-plugin-webfont-dl';

const extensions = [
  '.web.tsx',
  '.tsx',
  '.web.ts',
  '.ts',
  '.web.jsx',
  '.jsx',
  '.web.js',
  '.js',
  '.css',
  '.json',
  '.mjs',
  '.graphql.ts',
];

const development = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  clearScreen: true,
  plugins: [
    tsconfigPaths(),
    react({
      include: '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    }),
    relay({
      relayConfig: {
        src: '../../',
        schema: '../../schema.graphql',
        language: 'typescript',
        artifactDirectory: '../../__generated__/web',
        eagerEsModules: true,
      },
      codegen: false,
      module: 'esmodule',
    }),
    webfontDownload(),
  ].filter(Boolean),
  define: {
    global: 'window',
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(development),
    DEV: JSON.stringify(development),
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: extensions,
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: { transformMixedEsModules: true },
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      resolveExtensions: extensions,
      jsx: 'automatic',
      loader: { '.js': 'jsx', '.ts': 'tsx' }, 
  }},
});


Does anyone know the solution? Thank you

Solved the issue. It seems like Vite cannot resolve react native components by default so I used a plugin react-native-web and it worked
